# Difference between formatting & wipe

Tags: factory-reset, recovery-mode

Is there any difference in "wipe" (from the recovery mod) and factory reset from the android OS?

Does factory reset/wipe remove the custom ROM?

I need to know because after doing the "ALL wipe" from ultrajack recovery, I flashed a ROM. But the old boot animation, the system apps all remain!!

How can I fix this? or should I manually remove the system apps by mounting it as Rw. etc etc?

Comment: Do you mean pre-installed bloatware type apps (from a carrier, for example) when you say "system apps"?

Comment: Yes, like dataviz office suite etc.. but now I did WIPE /cust from ultrajack and they went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factory reset won't remove a custom ROM unless the backup image in the custom ROM is for a ROM other than itself.  This would be pretty unlikely.

I think we'd need to know your phone model and the ROM you used to help you figure out why it didn't write over the system apps.  That's definitely not normal.  Normally virtually no trace of the old ROM should be left.

Comment: Im using Huawei IDEOS u8150 and have ultrajack v6.2.2. I did the first option of "Wipe ALL data.." option in ultrajack and it said successful. Then I flashed rom from ZIP from sd card. The old boot animation and system apps remained. However when I re entered ultrajack and went to another option called "Wipe /cust" , the bloatware, boot animation etc went off; So My problem is solved anyway. Thanks for letting me know the difference!